# Appended bars wont draw on svg element

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to write a transitioning bar graph that uses two CVS files. I know that both of the files are loading properly because it shows in the console that the first one loads with the page and the second one loads when you click the update button.

The only thing that I have really thought of trying was changing the svg select to group instead of selecting all rectangles incase there was something screwed up there.

This block is creating the svg element, bringing in the first CSV file, and appending the rectangles onto the chart. My only thought for what the problem could be is that it is inside a function, but if I take it out of the function how do I bind the data to them?

```
//Creating SVG Element
var chart_w = 1000,
chart_h = 500,
chart_pad_x = 40,
chart_pad_y = 20;

var svg = d3.select('#chart')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', chart_w)
    .attr('height', chart_h);

//Defining Scales
var x_scale = d3.scaleBand().range([chart_pad_x, chart_w - 
chart_pad_x]).padding(0.2);
var y_scale = d3.scaleLinear().range([chart_pad_y, chart_h - 
chart_pad_y]);

//Data-------------------------------------------------------------------
d3.csv('data.csv').then(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        generate(data);  });

function generate(data){
//Scale domains
x_scale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){ return d }));
y_scale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){ return d })]);

//Create Bars
svg.select('rect')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('x', function(d, i){
            return x_scale(i);
        })
        .attr('y', function(d){
             return y_scale(d);
        })
        .attr('width', x_scale.bandwidth())

        .attr('height', function(d){
            return y_scale(d);
        })
        .attr('transform',
          "translate(0,0)")
        .attr('fill', '#03658C')
```

'''

The results I have experienced is a blank window with just the update button. As previously stated I know that the data is being generated because I can see it in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
svg.selectAll('rect')
    .data(data)
```

If you use `svg.select` this will only make the data binding with the first element found.

> d3.select(selector): Selects the first element that matches the specified selector string. If no elements match the selector, returns an empty selection. If multiple elements match the selector, only the first matching element (in document order) will be selected. For example, to select the first anchor element:

This should be clear if you inspect the DOM nodes.

To fix the issue lets change some things in your code:

Lets create a dummy fetch function:

```
(function simulateCSVFetch() {
    const data = [1,2,3,4,5];
    generate(data);
})();
```

You are also using a `scaleBand` with an incomplete domain by using the `extent` function:

> d3.extent(): Returns the minimum and maximum value in the given iterable using natural order. If the iterable contains no comparable values, returns [undefined, undefined]. An optional accessor function may be specified, which is equivalent to calling Array.from before computing the extent.

```
x_scale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { // cant use extent since we are using a scaleBand, we need to pass the whole domain
   return d;
}));
console.log(x_scale.domain()) // [min, max]
```

The `scaleBand` needs the whole domain to be mapped

> Band scales are typically used for bar charts with an ordinal or categorical dimension. The unknown value of a band scale is effectively undefined: they do not allow implicit domain construction.

If we continue using that scale we will be only to get two values for our x scale. Lets fix that with the correct domain:

```
x_scale.domain(data);
```

Lastly use the `selectAll` to create the data bind:

```
 svg.selectAll('rect')
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append('rect')
 .attr('x', function(d, i) {
   return x_scale(d);
 })
 .attr('y', function(d) {
   return chart_h - y_scale(d); // fix y positioning
 })
 .attr('width', x_scale.bandwidth())

 .attr('height', function(d) {
   return y_scale(d);
 })
 .attr('fill', '#03658C');
```

This should do the trick.

Complete code:

```
 var chart_w = 1000,
   chart_h = 500,
   chart_pad_x = 40,
   chart_pad_y = 20;

 var svg = d3
   .select('#chart')
   .append('svg')
   .style('background', '#f9f9f9')
   .style('border', '1px solid #cacaca')
   .attr('width', chart_w)
   .attr('height', chart_h);

 //Defining Scales
 var x_scale = d3.scaleBand()
   .range([chart_pad_x, chart_w - chart_pad_x])
   .padding(0.2);
 var y_scale = d3.scaleLinear()
   .range([chart_pad_y, chart_h - chart_pad_y]);

 //Data-------------------------------------------------------------------

 (function simulateCSVFetch() {
  const data = [1,2,3,4,5];
  generate(data);
 })();



 function generate(data) {
 console.log(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d }));
   //Scale domains
   x_scale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { // cant use extent since we are using a scaleBand, we need to pass the whole domain
     return d;
   }));
 // Band scales are typically used for bar charts with an ordinal or categorical dimension. The unknown value of a band scale is effectively undefined: they do not allow implicit domain construction.
   x_scale.domain(data);
   y_scale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
     return d
   })]);

   //Create Bars
   svg.selectAll('rect')
     .data(data)
     .enter()
     .append('rect')
     .attr('x', function(d, i) {
       return x_scale(d);
     })
     .attr('y', function(d) {
       return chart_h - y_scale(d); // fix y positioning
     })
     .attr('width', x_scale.bandwidth())

     .attr('height', function(d) {
       return y_scale(d);
     })
     .attr('fill', '#03658C');
 }
```

Working jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ot4xpfa3/25/)

---